# Buick LeSabre 2002 automatic transmission not working

Tags: transmission, buick, lesabre

My Buick went crazy 2 days ago, the car won't move if you transit to overdrive from neutral, though the RPM is moving. If I start from 1st transition or 2nd the car works properly. After 3rd I can go to overdrive normally.

I connected to the car computer but no errors and nothing wrong with gear oil??

Any ideas?

--Update--

now after a day i just tried to move the car from one place to another around 2 miles using manual transmission, after i stopped the car stopped going forward at all, and now only the reverse work.

--Solution--

The turned out to be an indication that the transmission is going bad, I bought a used one, the cost was around $700

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, we'd love to hear about it!

Comment: @Zaid I updated my answer

Comment: @OmarQa, your edit should be an answer to your own question.  I'll re-open it, you can edit it and congratulate yourself on solving your problem!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an indication that the transmission is going bad, I bought a used one from a scrap shop, the cost was around $700 with installation.